# When I choose an option in my comboBox it is also changing the option for the other comboBox to the samething and shouldn't

Tags: java, swing, combobox

I am making a unit converter and have ran into an issue with the comboBox's I have gotten rid of the rest of the code and have just enough for it to show the problem.

In my comboBox's the first one gives me a choice of: Length Units or Time Units, after I pick one it then loads a different models for each comboBox. This is where the problem comes in at. When I pick one of the options for either the: length or time model, it changes both comboBox's to the same choice and I do not want that. I want to be able to have a different choice for each box ex.( centimeters) and (meters)

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;



public class TestConverter extends javax.swing.JFrame {




public TestConverter() {
    initComponents();
    setSize(350,225);  //set the starting size of frame
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);     //on startup centers the frame
    comboBoxFrom.setSelectedIndex(0);    //comboBox starts at index 0(first item in list) -1 puts box empty
    comboBoxTo.setSelectedIndex(0);

}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    comboBoxFrom = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
    comboBoxTo = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
    btnReset = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Unit Converter2");
    setFont(new java.awt.Font("Copperplate Gothic Light", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    setResizable(false);

    comboBoxFrom.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Choose One..", "Length Units", "Time Units" }));
    comboBoxFrom.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            comboBoxFromActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    comboBoxTo.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Choose One..", " " }));
    comboBoxTo.setToolTipText("");
    comboBoxTo.setEnabled(false);
    comboBoxTo.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            comboBoxToActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    btnReset.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 204, 0));
    btnReset.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
    btnReset.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(204, 0, 0));
    btnReset.setText("Reset");
    btnReset.setActionCommand("Convert To");
    btnReset.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnResetActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(148, 148, 148)
                .addComponent(btnReset)
                .addContainerGap(617, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(187, 187, 187)
                .addComponent(comboBoxTo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 135, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(186, 186, 186)
            .addComponent(comboBoxFrom, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 135, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(35, 35, 35)
            .addComponent(comboBoxFrom, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(btnReset)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(comboBoxTo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(346, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void comboBoxFromActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

    String lengthUnits[] = {"Centimeters", "Feet", "Inches", "Kilometers", "Light Years", "Miles", "Meters", "Yards" };
    String timeUnits[] = {"Hours", "Milliseconds", "Minutes", "Seconds"};
    if(comboBoxFrom.getSelectedItem().equals("Length Units")){
        comboBoxTo.setEnabled(true);  //set the comboBoxTo to be activated
        DefaultComboBoxModel length = new DefaultComboBoxModel(lengthUnits);  //makes a new model and fills it from the array lengthUnits
        comboBoxFrom.setModel( length );
        comboBoxTo.setModel(length);
    }
    else if(comboBoxFrom.getSelectedItem().equals("Time Units")){
        comboBoxTo.setEnabled(true);   //set the comboBoxTo to be activated
        DefaultComboBoxModel time = new DefaultComboBoxModel(timeUnits);  //makes a new model and fills it from the array lengthUnits
        comboBoxFrom.setModel( time );
        comboBoxTo.setModel(time);
    }

}                                            

private void comboBoxToActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

}                                          

private void btnResetActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String comboStart[] = {"Choose one..", "Length Units", "Time Units"};
    DefaultComboBoxModel reset = new DefaultComboBoxModel(comboStart);
    comboBoxFrom.setModel(reset);
    comboBoxTo.setModel(reset);
    comboBoxFrom.setSelectedIndex(0); // starts the comboBox at index 0. type -1 to start it empty
    comboBoxTo.setSelectedIndex(0);
    comboBoxTo.setEnabled(false);



}                                        

public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ConverterV2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ConverterV2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ConverterV2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ConverterV2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new TestConverter().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton btnReset;
private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> comboBoxFrom;
private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> comboBoxTo;
// End of variables declaration                   

private void setIcon() { //method to get the icon image for jFrame
   setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("Icon.png"))); 
}
```

}

Comment: Your missing the most important code! You're not showing any of the sub-action performed methods. You need to simplify the code you post here to the minimal required to allow us to copy, compile and run it and show your problem, and nothing more, a [mcve].

Comment: You are showing too much of the wrong code.  If your problem is about two combo boxes, make a [mcve] without buttons and text fields, colours, fonts, etc

Comment: Ok I have update the code.

Comment: Please re-read the link: minimal means minimal. It should compile, run, and show the problem, and that's it. You've got lots of code not needed for the above, and you've got things that prevent the code from running including missing constants and an image requirement.

Comment: (1-) That is not an [mcve]. Your question is about selecting an item in a combo box and it is updating a second combo box. So all the other componenents are irrelevant to the problem. Post a proper `MCVE` with just the two working combo boxes on the frame. The point is for you to simplify the code if you want other people to look at it.

Comment: I have only the 2 comboBox and the reset button. Everything else has been deleted. I have ran it as is and it runs with the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    DefaultComboBoxModel length = new DefaultComboBoxModel(lengthUnits);  //makes a new model and fills it from the array lengthUnits
    comboBoxFrom.setModel( length );
    comboBoxTo.setModel(length);
```

> . When I pick one of the options for either the: length or time model, it changes both comboBox's to the same choice

Well your code is sharing the same model. Which means either combo box will update the same model.

You need two separate models:

```
    comboBoxFrom.setModel( new DefaultComboBoxModel( lengthUnits ) );
    comboBoxTo.setModel( new DefaultComboBoxModel( lengthUnits ) );
```

Comment: Thank you very much that fixed the problem, I would give you a upvote but it won't let since I don't have enough reputation.